# How do class variables work with Realm in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, realm

Since Xcode 8, it is possible to create class properties:

```
@property (class, nonatomic, assign) NSInteger currentId;
```

I'm wondering how these work with Realm, since it does not make sense to me that the property get duplicated for every instance, but the only attribute that (if I understand the documentation) does not get ignored is `readonly` which translates to *do not persist*...

Should I instead build a sort of super-manager-class-singleton-instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class property is like a syntax sugar, it is actually just a class method. Realm simply ignores them because they are not subject to persistence.

Comment: Which, I guess, means I need that Super Manager Singleton Instance Power... damned. Thanks :)